# SSIS Package failure when deployed in Sql server due to Version Mismatch

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database, iaas

currently i have deployed a SSIS package(built on visual studio 2015) in cloud iaas Sql server ( package has script task and script component along with another ssis tasks) when executed in sql server fails with below error . Although same when executed in my local works fine without any issue.

**Error**
*There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task "ST_71fc189aeb4a40b3aac7355e33225ca6" uses version 15.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services. To run the package, use the Script Task to create a new VSTA script. In most cases, scripts are converted automatically to use a supported version, when you open a SQL Server Integration Services package in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Integration Services.
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)*

**I tried multiple of approaches mentioned below as suggested in MSDN forum but nothing worked**
i)tried upgrading the package target version to 2016 and turned off validation for 64 bit
runtime(Failed).
ii) created and deployed a Dummy package with script task alone(Failed).
iii) Developed a package which was built on Lower version of Visual studio ( failed).

currently there server which i am deploying in has below version
Sql server Version : [ *Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)]

Also the Vm in which server is hosted has the GAC MSIL for Script TAsk of Version (v4.0_11 ,v4.0_12 ,v4.0_13 , v4.0_14) and the Integration Service of Version 2016 is installed in the sql database server.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How (what tool(s)) are you using to deploying to this IaaS? I see you attempted with dummy packages, did one of these have nothing in it or did they all contain script tasks?

Comment: While unrelated, you should put in a service request to have them patch that instance. RTM was released 2016-06-01. The [current set of patches](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2016x) was released 2020-05-28. There's been a bunch of fixes released that make SQL Server and SSIS more stable and secure.

Comment: @billinkc   i am using sql server Integration wizard to deploy the package in catalogue. and the dummy package has a script task with a simple code in it. Since my main package was throwing error i created a dummy one to test the issue.

Does installation of 2017 version going to help ? or shall i upgrade the current 2016 version with its latest patch ?

Comment: From a command line, if you type `where isdeploymentwizard.exe` it will report back, in order, the program it will used. Ensure that the executable used is the 130 version i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe`